# Regex to pass validation if specific number is not present

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I am woring on jquery validation. I have to apply a regex to reject -99999. I tried

```
^(?!.*[-]99999).*$
```

but this will reject -999999 which is actually not -99999. What should i do to reject only if value is exactly -99999.

my jquery rule is

```
numericMinFieldRule = {
            required                : true,
            min                     : -999999999,
            max                     : 999999999,
            number                  : true,
            regex                   : /^(?!.*-99999).*$/,
            messages                : {
                                        required: "This is a required field",
                                        regex: "-99999 is not allowed.",
                                    }
    };
```

Thanks.

Comment: Remove `.*` from the negative lookahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

`^(?!.*[-]99999$).*$`

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KuYcUf/3)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the string
- `(?!.*[-]99999$)` - negative lookahead to validate that exactly -99999 is not present in the string
- `.*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character but not a new-line character
- `$` - asserts the end of the string

Comment: why why why didnt i think about that. Spent almost 3 hours now. Thanks

Comment: you said .+ but there is no .+ rather .*

Comment: Updated. That was a typo

Comment: @MuneebMirza Please select it as the answer IF IT solved your problem.

Comment: i couldnt do it, min time limit was not reached yet :)